# Create SQL Login for Azure Active Directory User

Tags: azure

Problem : Configure Azure SQL DB so Azure AD Users can login to the server using SSMS, and be authenticated.

The Normal Process to configure a User in SQL is

- Create Login
- Create Users
- Assign Roles

However, I am not able to create Login in a way that Password does not need to be specified, and the user can Login.

Do I need to use this command ?
'
CREATE LOGIN login_name [FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER] { WITH  [,..]}

```
<option_list> ::=
    PASSWORD = {'password'}
    | SID = sid
    | DEFAULT_DATABASE = database
    | DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = language
```

'
How can we do this without having to create a password, since it will be Azure Active Directory Integrated ?

Comment: I have gone through all the microsoft docs, but not getting the answer.

Comment: It looks like you have to run that 'CREATE USER ... FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER' first on master database (SQL server level) and then on each database that you want to connect to... Documentation is not helpful, I agree on that :)

Answer (score 5):

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#create-contained-database-users-in-your-database-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities

The command is

```
CREATE USER <Azure_AD_principal_name> FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

For example:

```
CREATE USER [alice@fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

Comment: Thanks. But this works if you are an Active Directory Admin(Azure Portal), if not the Login does not work. Is there a way those who are not AAD Admin can Login.

Comment: you need to have admin privilege to execute that command but the users do not need to be admins.

Comment: Edit: Does not even need to be an admin to create the users
"To create an Azure AD-based contained database user (other than the server administrator that owns the database), connect to the database with an Azure AD identity, as a user with at least the ALTER ANY USER permission."

Comment: Ya I did that, but the user that was added is not able to Login to the Azure SQL DB using SSMS. (Authentication :- Active Directory Integrated). The is where i wondered, do we need to create a Login first and then the user ?

Comment: No, you don’t need to create a login. Did you also assign at least one role to the user? Such as dbreader

Comment: It works for me.