# Create user login on a local instance of SQL Server - for an Azure AD user

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a local instance of SQL Server installed. I installed it as the machine's administrator.

Now I want to create a user for a database on that server, but the user is not a local windows user, but an Azure AD user.

I tried to execute the code mentioned in the [Create SQL Login for Azure Active Directory User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57186956/create-sql-login-for-azure-active-directory-user)

```
CREATE USER [alice@fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com] 
FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

but I always get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'PROVIDER'

Now to reiterate, it is not an Azure SQL database, it's a machine's local SQL Server hosting its own databases.

Comment: *"I have a **local** instance"* That question is for hosts in Azure, as noted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-database-users-in-your-database-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities) linked to in the answer.

Comment: Yeah won't work locally as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't use Azure AD user for on-premises SQL Server user.

The link you have shared is only applicable for Azure PaaS services like Azure SQL Database, Azure Managed Instance, etc.

As per this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview)

[image]